# Align Icon by Baseline in Stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to center an icon by its baseline, in the center of the Stack:

[image: this image]

I try this

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Tst")),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            Positioned(
                bottom: context.size.height / 2,
                width: context.size.width,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add_location,
                    size: 100,
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

But a receive the error:

> "Cannot get size during build." 
>   "The size of this render object has not yet been determined because the framework is still in the"

Comment: alternatively use `Container` combined with `Center`, or only `Center`, or Column with main axis center and cross axis center. there are a lot of way to get it done.

Comment: The problem with the center is that it centers the center of the icon. I need to center relative to the base.
Using Center and Column I get [this](https://imgur.com/LCRH3uW)

Answer (score 0):

> "Cannot get size during build." "The size of this render object has
> not yet been determined because the framework is still in the process of building widget"

The error is very obvious. You can not calculate the size of the widget before it is built.

A better alternative is to use [`Center`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) widget in this case as suggested by hayi:

```
Center(
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.add_location,
      size: 100,
    ),
  )),
```

The above code is just an example.

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem with the center is that it centers the center of the icon. I need to center relative to the base. Using Center and Column I get [this](https://imgur.com/LCRH3uW)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the size of the context like that. You have to use `MediaQuery`. Also use `left` and `right` with `0.0` to center the widget horizontally.

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Tst")),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add_location,
                size: 100.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```